# Retain Search Form Data Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

Trying to build a search on my homepage with simple_form (Pretty much same as formtastic). The search works fine and im getting my results but after submission I want to retain the vales with what the user submitted.

I am using a namespace for my form so how can I retain the data for the form. Here is some code which may help.

Controller

```
def index
  @results = Property.search(params[:search])
end
```

View

```
%h1 Search Form
= simple_form_for(:search) do |f|
    = f.input :location, :as => :select, :collection => Location.all.asc(:name)
        = f.input :type, :collection => PropertyType.all.asc(:name)
        = f.input :bedrooms, :collection => 1..10,
    %p.box
        = f.button :submit

-if @results
    %h1 Search Results
    .results
        - @results.each do |property|
            .result
                %h1= property.title
```

Within the Index controller I have tried all sorts of things ie

```
@search = params[:search]
```

But each time I try something the search breaks.

What am I doing wrong ?

Hope you can advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to do as Xavier Holt suggested, and pass in values to each input. The simpleform doco suggests:

```
 = f.input :remember_me, :input_html => { :value => '1' }
```

The other approach is to have simpleform do it for you. SimpleForm will automatically populate the fields with values if you give it something like an activerecord object.

In this case, that means creating a model object:

```
class PropertySearchCriteria
  attr_accessor :location, :type, :bedrooms
  def initialize(options)
    self.location = options[:location]
    self.type = options[:bedrooms]
    self.bedrooms = options[:bedrooms]
  end
end
```

Then, change your controller:

```
def index
  @property_search_criteria = PropertySearchCriteria.new(params[:search])
  @results = Property.search(@property_search_criteria)
end
```

(you'll have to change the Property.search method as well)

Then, change your simple_form_for:

```
= simple_form_for(:search, @property_search_criteria) do |f|
```

And if you do all that, and get the stars to align just right, then simpleform will pre-populate the form fields all by itself. You may have to add some stuff to PropertySearchCriteria to get simpleform to be properly happy.

This is a lot of stuffing around just to get the values showing up, but it'll keep you sane if you need to add validations.

Comment: Hey Iain, This is alot more like the what I need.  I just started to go down the route of creating a search resource but this is also nice. I have tied this quickly but I get an error. You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!  Which is from app/models/property_search_criteria.rb:8:in `initialize'  I tried adding creating it as an empty array first ??

Comment: Adding  self.location = options[:location] unless options.blank?  Clears up that problem. But seems overkill to add for every item. I will keep going. TY

Comment: oops, sorry. In place of "def initialize(options)", do "def initialize(options = {})". That way options is never blank.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar in the app I'm working on (I'm not using formtastic, but this should be at least very close to something that works for you).  I got around it by making sure `@search` was a hash in the controller:

```
@search = params[:search] || {}
```

And then using `@search[:key]` as the `:value` option in all my search inputs (There's a chance you'll need to set `@search.default = ''` to get this working):

```
<%= text_field_tag :name, :value => @search[:name] %>
```

And that's all it took.  As my app is getting more complicated and AJAXy, I've been thinking of moving the search parameters into the session information, which you might want to do now to stay ahead, but if you're just looking for a simple solution, this worked great for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not work for me also. I get other errors ie undefined method `location' for {}:Hash

Comment: @Lee - Well, that's all I've got - looks like formtastic must be more different than I thought.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can try storing your parameters in session like so:

```
def index
  @results = Property.search(params[:search])
  store_search
end

def store_search
  session[:search] = params[:search]
end
```

just be sure when you are done with the parameters that you clean them up

```
...
clear_search if session[:search]

def clear_search
  session[:search] = nil
end
```

Comment: hmm session should help you persist the data.  do you happen to know if its never getting stored in session or is it just being cleared out by something else along the way?

Comment: Hi Will, It is getting stored but if I add back in @search = session[:search] I still get form errors,  undefined method `location' ??

Comment: interesting i wonder if storing :location in your hash as :select is causing issues.  if you remove the :as in your form or ignore location altogether, will the form render then?

Comment: The :as => :select is formtastic ways if displaying a select element. I cant see how that would make a difference. ?

Comment: i am not too familiar with formtastic so i cant tell you for sure.  the undefined method 'location' error just made me think that there was simply a mismatch between the hash you are passing from the form and whatever model binder is in play